# Are "How much" and "How many" used in Object Questions, Subject Questions or both?

Tags: questions, subjects, objects

I came across with a text saying that questions starting with "How much" and "How many" are considered Subject Questions. I understand that in examples like:

- How many people are in the party?
- How much traffic is in your city?

These questions don't have a Subject.

However, there are other questions like:

- How many children do you have?
- How much ink did you use?

In these questions, there are subject pronouns.
So, can we use "How much" and "How many" in both kinds of questions?

Comment: All these sentences have subjects.  Without subjects a sentence cannot be formed.  The sentences are correct.  Are there questions called subject questions and object questions?

Comment: Could you tell me what the subject in every question is?

Comment: @Ands Hawk; you may see the answer below

Comment: Is the text you're referring to available online where we can read it ourselves?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Just as "What bit the man?" and "What did the man bite?" are both correct, you can have:

> How many dogs bit the man?

and

> How many men did the dog bite?

In the first question, the subject is the interrogative "How many dogs" and in the second question the subject is "the dog".

Answer (score 0):

The subjects in the sentences are people, traffic, you, and you, in the respective order.

It is just that the sentences’ have been written in the interrogative form which doesn't mean they have no subjects.

For example,

You have x number of children.

Have you….?

Yes, you have…

No, you do not have any child/children.

Have you not (haven’t you) any child/children?

How many children have you (do you have?)

Same sentence, when written in different ways, doesn't lose the sentence.